# recreate hyperlink, or create net hyperlink VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets. In one of the sheet (sheet1) I have 1 hyperlink with file address \sii\picture\as.jpg hyperlink is named "LINK". I need to re create this hyperlink without "formats" (background color and any of them). I need to do this using VBA.

when I try this I get an error

```
Localization = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address

Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("sheet2").Cells(2, 2), Address:=Localization, TextToDisplay:="LINK"
```

---

if I make something like

```
sheets("Sheet1").select

range (Cells(1,1)).select

SELECTION.Copy

sheets("Sheet2").select

range (Cells(1,1)).select

Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
```

I get good hiperlink but this hiperlink have formated background and any things from first sheet, and my screen is blinking because excel is jumping between sheet1 and sheet2

Comment: To recover link correct the first line:     Localization = Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks(1).Address after that, work fine

Comment: If you leave ". Range("A1")" you need to know the number of hyperlink.
after all i make it in one line and it works.

Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1), Address:=(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address), TextToDisplay:="LINK"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. You may have to amend it to fit withing your existing code

```
Sub Main()

Dim rngDest As Range
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim wkshtSource As Worksheet
Dim wkshtDest As Worksheet
Dim urlSource As String

    ' Set Worksheet and Range variables for easy reference
    Set wkshtSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wkshtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngSource = wkshtSource.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rngDest = wkshtDest.Cells(2, 2)
    'Gets the address of the hyperlink to copy
    urlSource = rngSource.Hyperlinks(1).Address

    'Creates Hyperlink on second page
    rngDest.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngDest, Address:=urlSource, TextToDisplay:="Link"

End
```